# Qooxdoo focus partially hides button image

Tags: qooxdoo

I'm trying to make a ToggleButton as small as possible while still retaining the image; however, when the button has focus it moves the image to the right and partially hides it. How can I overcome this? I've tried padding and margins but neither seemed to work.

Here's an example:
http://preview.tinyurl.com/8y4arrl

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce the issue when toggling the button twice (on - off), and then moving between hovered and not hovered. Please [open a bug](http://bugs.qooxdoo.org/) for this. It has to do with the decoration of the focussed and hovered states, but only shows when you set dimensions and padding as you did. Please add your Playground link and describe the procedure (on - off - hover - not hover). Thanks.